# Update Assign to field with Outlook vbs

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

In the Outlook i have create a custom form in Task form. I use it to assign task to other users. Now i try to add some code when a user not fill the assign to field (for example if the task is for him to check it when save the task and ask him if need to add himself as assigned user. My problem is that  i can't update the field assigned to if it's empty.I get the error  My code is the following:

```
   Sub Item_Write(ByVal Name) 
      Set objPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Assign Task")
      Set objControl = objPage.Controls("RecipientControl1")
      Set objControl2 = objPage.Controls("Textbox1")
      Set objControl4 = objPage.Controls("Textbox4")

      Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      Set objNS = oMsg.Session

     MyValue= objControl2.Value
     MyValue4= objControl4.Value

     if MyValue= "" then
     if Msgbox ("Task isn't assign to anybody. Do you want to assign yourself?", vbYesNo)=vbYes then 
 objControl.Value=objNS.CurrentUser.Name


 End if
 End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution,

I use the event Item_Close and Outlook property name for Recipient control and not Control name in Vbs. Find below my code that is working and form not close until user assign the task someone.

```
     Function Item_Close()
      Set objPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Assign Task")
      Set objControl = objPage.Controls("Textbox1")
      Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
      Set objContro2 = objPage.Controls("Frame1")


      assigned=objControl.Value
      'Use always Outlook property names and not Control Properties(as RecipientControl in case)
       if assigned= "" then
        info =Msgbox ("The task is not assigned to a user. Do you want to assign yourself?", vbYesNo)
      Select Case info
       Case 6
        'Use always Outlook property names and not Control Properties(as RecipientControl in case)
     Set myAssignedTo = Item.Recipients.Add(objNS.CurrentUser.Name)
     Me.Save
      Case 7
         MsgBox "You must Assign Task to a user before save it.", vbExclamation

        Item_Close=False
        Item.GetInspector.SetCurrentFormPage "Assign Task"
   End Select
 End if
End Function
```